# KSH Verifying if a number exist in a list

Tags: arrays, ksh

I have a list of numbers, around 200 and at the beginning of my ksh I want to verify if parameter 1 is one of this numbers.

I solved this with a big if, but I think that a more elegant solution must exist.

In example, something like this, but in ksh

```
if $1 in (50, 28, 500, 700, 1, 47) then
   do what I want
else
   exit
end if
```

Any idea to start working?

Thanks.

Luis

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
case $1 in ( 50 | 28 | 500 | 700 | 1 | 47 ) 
  echo ¨Found!¨
;;
*)
   echo ¨NOT found!¨
;;
esac
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The case statement works for short lists if the list changes or is long, that can get ugly in a hurry. Another idea is to use an associative array.  I set up a list of 100 random numbers in the file `rand.txt` and ran this script to check for numbers on the list:

```
typeset -A numList
for num in $( < rand.txt )
do
    numList[$num]=$num
done

if [[ -n ${numList[$1]} ]]
then
    echo "do what I want"
else
    echo 'not interesting'
fi
```

If you don't want a separate file with the numbers, this also works:

```
typeset -A numList
(
cat <<EOF
72
107
104
82
20
21
EOF
) | while read num
do
    numList[$num]=$num
done
if [[ -n ${numList[$1]} ]]
then
    echo "do what I want"
else
    echo 'not interesting'
fi
```

These also work on bash.

Comment: I like your first solution with a file, but without loading all the numbers in a list and stopping when it is found.

#!/bin/bash
for num in $( < x.txt)
do
    if [ $num = $1 ]
    then
        echo "do what I want"
        exit
    else
        echo "$num="$num" and $1="$1
    fi
done
 echo 'not interesting'
exit